# passing toml file name to spring context

Tags: spring, zeebe

the [zeebe-broker](https://zeebe.io) has to be started with the path to a configuration toml file. However, in a spring context, I only have this information at runtime (its a cli argument).
How can I define my spring configuration (annotation based) to provide a bean for a broker that is initialized with the given path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:  The command line args can be accessed in the following way:

```
 static Function<Environment, Optional<String>> tomlFileFromEnv = environment -> {
    String[] args = environment.getProperty("nonOptionArgs", String[].class, new String[0]);
    if (args == null || args.length == 0) {
        return Optional.empty();
    } else if (args.length > 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("requires exactly one cli argument, the tomlFile.");
    } else {
        return Optional.of(args[0]);
    }

};
```